# List in property file is deserialized to String using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson2

In our application we are trying to read a flat property file using Jackson to match the properties to our POJO. The property file contains a list, but it seems that is deserialized to a single String.
This is the error I get: "**Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of VALUE_STRING token**"

This is how the input file looks like

```
test=Just a test 
status=A, B, C
```

Also tried

```
status=[A, B, C]
status=["A", "B", "C"]
```

This is our POJO

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BasicPOJO {

  @JsonProperty("status")
  List<String> status;

  @JsonProperty("test")
  String test;

 //Getter and setter ..
}
```

And this is how we map it

```
public void test1() {
// Read configuration file from classpath
InputStream in = WMSApplicationProperties.class.getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("application.properties");

LOGGER.debug("Reading with JSON layout");
JavaPropsMapper mapper = new JavaPropsMapper();


try {
  JavaPropsSchema schema = JavaPropsSchema.emptySchema()
      .withoutPathSeparator();

  BasicPOJO myProperties = mapper.readerFor(BasicPOJO.class)
      .with(schema)
      .readValue(in);      
  } catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Any idea why the list is being treated as a String 
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your JSON property file should look like this : `{ "status" : [ "A", "B", "C" ] }`

Comment: It is not a JSON property file, it is a clasic propery file (that unfortunatelly I can not change). So the format is property=value

Comment: If so, your `BasicPOJO` won't work. Does your `status` property is supposed to contain a JSON Object or just a list ?

Comment: My status property is supposed to contain a list of coma separated values that I expect it will be converted to a list when being deserialized

Comment: Why don't you use a basic [String split(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) instead ? You clearly don't JSON parser for this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the only way to specify a list when reading a property file (not JSON formatted) is specifying the properties like this:

```
status.1=A
status.2=B
status.3=C
```

Unfortunately the format: status=A, B, C is not possible